µBlock: How to Add a CSS-class in a Filter?
µBlock (uBlock) provides action operator :remove-class(), but how can I add a CSS-class?
On a site an element alternates between two CSS-classes. I have a rule with :remove-class() that is triggered every now and then, but then the page looks weird. Therefore, I want to remove one class as I do now, but also add the other CSS-class.
example.com##.ad_wrapper:watch-attr(class):remove-class(ad_wrapper-visible)
!how to add class "ad_wrapper-hidden"?


official documentation states:

uBO supports only the following, and anything else gets ignored:
(...)
cap_user_stylesheet   -> true on Firefox, Chromium 66+, -> supports style injection by tabs.insertCSS

the syntax would be probably something like this (pseudocode, not tested):
!#if cap_user_stylesheet 
example.com##.tabs.insertCSS(file: "content-style.css")  
!#endif

All the options possible to use with tabs.insertCSS are available here.
There's also another option: subject:style action operator.
Another possibility is using AG's CSS injection rules as stated at the bottom of this documentation.
I'd specifically look at the :is() pseudo-class.
I hope it helps.
